# content slider which slides onclick menu item?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dependency-injection, slider

please help me. I would like create a div slider, which horizontally slides if someone click at menu item or if someone click next/prev button.
Here is a illustration http://s14.postimg.org/3rfsk9sjl/slider.png
[image: illustration]

Here is a HTML code:

```
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>BIO</li>
                <li>MAIN</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="bio">

            </div>
            <div id="main">

            </div>
            <div id="contact">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What you had tried for this here we will help if you are stuck anywhere, you are asking question like some one write a code for you, please add some javascript code

Comment: Please attempt to write the code yourself. SO is not a site where people will write it for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake, I dont want to people who will write code for me. I want to learn it yourself. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here: [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), it could help you.